# Is there a word for "to be built"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there was a singular word that says "this will be constructed ( but it isn't constructed right now )".  Is there such a word?

-- not too sure about whether it is transitive or not, but it would be used to describe something like "[to be built of bricks wall]" or "[to be built of Lego] house".

Comment: "Laid out a blueprint for" could work. I can't think of a singular word. "Blueprinted" is apparently a word, but is awkward and I would hesitate using it.

Comment: @user2238698 Could you specify if you're looking for a transitive or intransitive verb?

Comment: "In the works," more colloquially, is also a term that would work well. "The building project is in the works."

Comment: "planned" is the usual closest in most real estate markets

Comment: **Pending** means "to be done/created". It's not so often used for construction since it's less specific about what stage the construction is at than "proposed", "planned", "scheduled" etc, but it is sometimes, e.g. [this article:](http://www.gazettextra.com/news/2012/oct/13/milton-travel-center-likely-remain-cut-pending-byp/) "The prospects appear dim for a Milton gas station that’s being cut off from passing traffic by **the pending Highway 26 bypass**"

Comment: I think the reason this is so hard to find a single word for is "to be constructed by" or "to be built by" is both in the passive voice, as opposed to "to construct" or "to build", which is the active voice. I don't know if there are any verbs that work in the passive voice without needing auxiliaries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Planned** fits.

*Plan* (verb) - to intend or expect to do.

> The *planned* bridge will have four lanes.

Comment: I deleted my answer of *planned*. It would be better to give a source or a link for your definition.

Answer (score 6):

Consider *slated*.

> *The bridge is slated for construction starting February 1.*

[slate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slate): to plan or designate (something) for a particular place and time; schedule.

Answer (score 5):

I would say *[scheduled](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/schedule)*.  It gets rid of some of the ambiguity of when.

Comment: "Scheduled" suggests a definite timetable, which might not be the case.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - man I think you have nailed the definition of scheduled.  Good insight.

Answer (score 4):

The **projected** bridge will be one-way, but no one knows why.

Answer (score 0):

A building **under construction** or **under development** can be used to convey your meaning.

Comment: I like the latter term better, as it implies a project that isn't necessarily in motion, rather than one that is already ongoing.

Comment: But this means that it is already being built.  Something is under construction once they start working on it.

Comment: It is not clear what OP is looking for, all suggested forms may fit in my opinion unless more details are given.

Comment: @Elian "under development" works in regards to something "that will be built." "Though it's not set in stone, the plan is under development." It may not be the best of the whole lot, but it's definitely a viable option.

Comment: @njboot OP should clarify what he actually wants. "Under development" is not a single word nor an intransitive verb for "to be built." My primary answer sticked with what the OP "seems" to be looking for.

Comment: @Elian agreed. That's why I'm just throwing out options in the comment section versus adding a response. Also just up voted "slated." I think that's the best one so far.

Comment: @njboot It's not. I was right from the start. Check out the OP update. ;-)

Comment: @Elian yes, I see that - though I don't think you should of deleted! I'm even less clear on what the OP is seeking now given the edit...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14641/discussion-between-njboot-and-elian).

Comment: @Elian next time :) Cheers.

Comment: @njboot "This will be built" implies that "this" is a building or structure, not a plan. To say that a building or structure is under development implies strongly that construction (or, at the very least, preparation of the site) has begun. The plans being under development is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

*Prospective* and *future* also work.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the amount of pre-work you want to imply. "Scheduled" seems to imply more has been done than "Planned". "Proposed" implies even less, just that it's been thought of and mentioned, whereas "Envisioned" seems to require the minimum pre-work, i.e. only that someone thought about building it, (anything less would probably preclude the "to be" in "to be built"), so I'd go with "Envisioned" if I had no other information or intent.

Answer (score -1):

Pending works well here.

: not yet decided or acted on

: happening or likely to happen soon

source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pending